# Application unit testing in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am testing an application in IOS5 using OCUnit.  Before posting my problem I read all the relevant posts here as much I could.  It really helped.  I am now facing the problem below ,which I tried to narrate as clearly as possible.

1. My application has a login screen which is nothing but a view controller say: initialController. The root controller of my app delegate is the Navigation controller. The property initWithRootViewController of the Navigation controller is set with this initialController.
2. Now after logging in , the application loads another controller and I want to do unit testing in that controller without having to go through this login process.
3. Post login, another controller say PostloginController gets loaded, this controller's Navigation item is customized with 2 button's say: button1 and button2.
   These buttons are added as the subviews of UIBarButtonItem and this UIBarButtonItem is set as the rightBarButtonItem of the PostloginController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.(pseudo code)
4. finally PostLoginController is pushed in the Navigation controller
   navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:postLoginController.(pseudo code)
5. I have to write unit test code which on button1's UIControlEventTouchUpInside should launch another controller say :Newcontroller. 
   Loading this new controller on button1's event complete one test case.

My problem is that I don't get the subview of UIBarButtonItem which should be 2 buttons.  The log show me there is one controller in the Navigation Controller and only one subview. My code is as follows:

```
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];    
    // Set-up code here.

    self.appDelegate = (MYAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate ];
    self.navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
}

- (void)testAppDelegate
{
    STAssertNotNil(self.appDelegate, @"Cannot find the application delegate");

    NSArray *tempArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    NSLog(@"Number of controllers in navigationController = %i", [tempArray count]);
}

- (void) testButton1
{
    //self.myController = (PostLoginController*)self.navigationController.topViewController;

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;

    UIView *customView = barButtonItem.customView;       
    NSArray *subviews1 = customView.subviews;

    NSLog (@ "Got subviews");
    NSLog(@"Number of subviews = %i", [subviews1 count]);

    if ([subviews1 count] == 0)
    {
        NSLog (@ "no subviews");
    }

    for (UIView* view in subviews1)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", view);

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)view;
            NSLog (@ " UIButton parsed");

            // Check if Button1 clicked.
            NSData *data1=UIImagePNGRepresentation([btn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
            NSData *data2=UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"BUTTON1.png"]);

            if([data1 isEqualToData:data2])   // CHECKING IF BUTTON1 OR BUTTON2 PRESSED BY IMAGE SINCE THEY DONT HAVE ANY TAGS SET.
            {
                [btn sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
                STAssertTrue([self.navigationController.visibleViewController isMemberOfClass: [NewController class]], @" NewController failed to load!"); //BUTTON1 CLICK SHOULD LAUNCH NEWCONTROLLER - COMPLETES ONE TEST CASE.
            }
        }
    }
}
```